# Failed to download. Use the purchases page to try again

Tags: applications, macos, install, mac-appstore

I'm having trouble downloading Asset Catalog Creator from the Mac App Store. I just purchased the app and it's failing to download. I don't know if they problem is unique to this particular app or given that there are similar questions out there for Xcode and iPhoto I'm unsure if I'm stuck in some weird App Store state. I always get the following in the Purchased tab when I try to install the app.

[image: mac app store purchase fail]

Not exactly great news for developers trying to make money through the Mac App Store.

I've tried deleting ~/Library/Application\ Support/App\ Store and and ~/Library/Caches/com.apple.appstore and also logging out and back in again. I notice the Debug menu which used to be enabled via `defaults write com.apple.appstore ShowDebugMenu -bool true` and which contained "App Store Reset" functionality has now gone so that is not a solution I can use as others have claimed worked in the past.

Does anybody else have any ideas that I can try? I'm on:
ProductName:    Mac OS X (Sierra)
ProductVersion: 10.12.5
BuildVersion:   16F73

I found the following in Console.app:

```
error   19:23:20.750152 +0100   storedownloadd  NSURLConnection finished with error - code -1100
default 19:23:20.750361 +0100   storedownloadd  *** Assertion failure in -[SoftwareInstallOperation _startInstall], /Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/Commerce/Commerce-583.17/CommerceKit/iTunes Protocol/Built Into App/SoftwareInstallOperation.m:303
default 19:23:20.750684 +0100   storedownloadd  error Error Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=-1100 "The installation could not be started." UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=The installation could not be started., NSUnderlyingError=0x7fb6ab757e80 {Error Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=-1100 "The requested URL was not found on this server." UserInfo={NSUnderlyingError=0x7fb6ab752a10 {Error Domain=kCFErrorDomainCFNetwork Code=-1100 "The requested URL was not found on this server." UserInfo={NSErrorFailingURLStringKey=file:///var/folders/cw/wbywkv7j7ldb_2d8ttpx7s940000gn/C/com.apple.appstore/809625456/ypr897306315285014831.pkg/index.sproduct, NSLocalizedDescription=The requested URL was not found on this server., NSErrorFailingURLKey=file:///var/folders/cw/wbywkv7j7ldb_2d8ttpx7s940000gn/C/com.apple.appstore/809625456/ypr897306315285014831.pkg/index.sproduct}}, NSErrorFailingURLStringKey=file:///var/folders/cw/wbywkv7j7ldb_2d8ttpx7s940000gn/C/com.apple.appstore/809625456/ypr897306315285014831.pkg/index.sproduct, NSErrorFailingURLKey=file:///var/folders/cw/wbywkv7j7
default 19:23:20.750898 +0100   storedownloadd  underlyingError Error Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=-1100 "The requested URL was not found on this server." UserInfo={NSUnderlyingError=0x7fb6ab752a10 {Error Domain=kCFErrorDomainCFNetwork Code=-1100 "The requested URL was not found on this server." UserInfo={NSErrorFailingURLStringKey=file:///var/folders/cw/wbywkv7j7ldb_2d8ttpx7s940000gn/C/com.apple.appstore/809625456/ypr897306315285014831.pkg/index.sproduct, NSLocalizedDescription=The requested URL was not found on this server., NSErrorFailingURLKey=file:///var/folders/cw/wbywkv7j7ldb_2d8ttpx7s940000gn/C/com.apple.appstore/809625456/ypr897306315285014831.pkg/index.sproduct}}, NSErrorFailingURLStringKey=file:///var/folders/cw/wbywkv7j7ldb_2d8ttpx7s940000gn/C/com.apple.appstore/809625456/ypr897306315285014831.pkg/index.sproduct, NSErrorFailingURLKey=file:///var/folders/cw/wbywkv7j7ldb_2d8ttpx7s940000gn/C/com.apple.appstore/809625456/ypr897306315285014831.pkg/index.sproduct, NSLocalizedDescription=The requested URL was not found on this server.}
default 19:23:20.751109 +0100   storedownloadd  localException [PKProduct productByLoadingProductAtURL:file:///var/folders/cw/wbywkv7j7ldb_2d8ttpx7s940000gn/C/com.apple.appstore/809625456/ypr897306315285014831.pkg] failed Error Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=-1100 "The requested URL was not found on this server." UserInfo={NSUnderlyingError=0x7fb6ab752a10 {Error Domain=kCFErrorDomainCFNetwork Code=-1100 "The requested URL was not found on this server." UserInfo={NSErrorFailingURLStringKey=file:///var/folders/cw/wbywkv7j7ldb_2d8ttpx7s940000gn/C/com.apple.appstore/809625456/ypr897306315285014831.pkg/index.sproduct, NSLocalizedDescription=The requested URL was not found on this server., NSErrorFailingURLKey=file:///var/folders/cw/wbywkv7j7ldb_2d8ttpx7s940000gn/C/com.apple.appstore/809625456/ypr897306315285014831.pkg/index.sproduct}}, NSErrorFailingURLStringKey=file:///var/folders/cw/wbywkv7j7ldb_2d8ttpx7s940000gn/C/com.apple.appstore/809625456/ypr897306315285014831.pkg/index.sproduct, NSErrorFailingURLKey=file:///var/folders/cw/wbywkv7j7ldb_2d8ttpx7s940000gn/C/com.ap
```

Looks like it's failing to connect to the correct URL?

Answer (score 1):

This can happen as the app store prepares to serve a different version of the app, such as when an update is being made ready for sale. Try again later.

Comment: Still not working... :/